# With xpath how do I correctly match all inner text

Tags: html, xpath

The InnerText attribute in Html returns all text including children. How do I replicate this with xpath?

For example with the following xpath:

```
//SPAN[normalize-space()='mycooltext']
```

I am trying to match

```
<span>mycooltext</span>
```

but also what to find

```
<span>
  <span>my
    <span>
      cool
    </span>
    text
   </span>
</span>
```

In both cases the root span inner text is "mycooltext".

I realize the normalize-space will strip some of the spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `descendant-or-self` axis

```
//span/descendant-or-self::*[normalize-space() = 'my cool text']
```

Note that `normalize-space` won't remove the spaces between the words

Demo here - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/fdbdafbe-22a5-4fac-a249-30c92dcb143a

If you really need to match the text with all spaces removed, this seems to work...

```
//span/descendant-or-self::*[translate(normalize-space(), ' ', '') = 'mycooltext']
```

Demo - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/e893f3e1-6d57-445c-9802-d7525bcd6b31